# Q: How do I add nicehash support to open-ethereum-pool for musicoin

Tags: ethereum, redis-server, go-ethereum

I have a fork of open-ethereum-pool by techievee

src: https://github.com/techievee/open-ethereum-pool

I can connect normal GPU miners without any issue [Connected Miners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmpe1.png)
However I am presented with an error every time I try and connect NiceHash to my pool

```
Notice: Pool verificator may not be 100% accurate and may report pool being compatible while in fact it is not compatible or vice versa. Always discuss with pool operator if you encounter any issues with the pool verificator.

Pool host: music.hashing.party
Pool port: 8008
Pool user: 0x63965fa987ea766455e78c581df7682a0732fdff
Pool pass: #
Algorithm: DaggerHashimoto

Resolving pool host music.hashing.party... OK
Establishing connection with proxy... OK
Establishing connection with pool 45.118.189.1:8008... OK
Sending eth_submitLogin... OK
Received authorization result... OK
Sending eth_getWork... OK
Error: Read timed out
Your pool is shown as incompatible therefore we encourage you to contact pool operator to make sure that the pool is using minimal/starting pool share difficulty which is compatible with our service (and thus compatible with today's miners), please send them link to our FAQ on this topic: https://www.nicehash.com/index.jsp?p=faq#faqb3. Thank you!
```

If anyone can provide assistance or point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nicehash port is different, i know that you have to use 8018 for ethereum classic.

Comment: Hi, I would suggest you adding some extra info, like quoting and linking the doc, to improve your answer.